# Displaying relevancy distribution in Lucene/SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, relevance

We're using Lucene/SOLR and we want to display a distribution graph of relevancy scores for all results. We're thinking iterating through all the results would be very inefficient, any suggestions how to do this 'on the fly'? The main purpose is to allow users to remove results that are deemed of low relevancy (or we might do it for them) - any other solutions out there?

Comment: the main idea of collector in Lucene is that it only scores enough documents to maintain top-K results that you've asked initally (lets say 10, page 1), going through all results to score them all would be equally difficult even to collect the distribution of scores